# How do I reference an image inside the Setup function in the Composition API in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How do I reference an image in the Setup function in the Composition API? The path is '../assets/pic.png'

If I use the path directly inside the template, as the src in an img tag, the image displays on the page. When I inspect it, it shows the image name, followed by an id, then the file extension e.g: “/img/pic.123456.png”. I *can* do it like this to get what I want, but it doesn’t seem like the correct way of doing things in Vue.

I’m thinking it should be something like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img src="pic">
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {

    setup(){

        const pic = ref('../assets/pic.png')

        return  { pic }
    }  

}

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

I believe it would work like this in the Options API (without ‘ref’, of course). I can’t get it to work with the Composition API. I'm thinking it may be something to do with the 'id'. Also how would I reference images in an array?

Thanks.

Comment: to reference images in an array, you will regularly use a combination of v-for. You can read about [using referencing an array in the v-for in the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for).

Answer (score 2):

You need to require the image first with the **require** function, and then pass the returned value to **ref**. and you should bind the src attribute with **v-bind**.

here is a complete example based on your code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img v-bind:src="pic">
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import { ref } from 'vue'
export default {

    setup(){

        const pic = ref(require('../assets/pic.png'))

        return  { pic }
    }  

}

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: I do the same but got an error that ` require`  is not defined. @ayoub

Comment: require will only work if you are using webpack and not vite

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and using require didnt work for me, finally, I got this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img v-bind:src="pic">
    </div>
</template>


<script>

import pic from '../assets/pic.png'
export default {

    setup(){
    }  

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From me, using vue composition style it worked this way:

```
<script setup lang="js">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import imageOrigin from '../assets/images/gestionalmacen.png'

const image = imageOrigin

</script>

<template>
    <div class="tituloPagina">
        <img v-bind:src="image">
        <h1>Gestor de Almacen</h1>
    </div>
    
</template>
```

Here, first I import the img url and then I create a constant with that link, the one I can call at the template.

Comment: There is no need for reassignment of the image origin inside a const, you can directly pass it to the src atribute like the previous example.

Comment: @SamuelRIGAUD thank u :)